# How do I convert 234.35 into Binary?

Tags: binary

I need to convert the above into Binary. I'm at a loss here. 
Can you include full information on how you got the answer too?. 
Step by step would be great!

Comment: Sorry, that should be 234.35^10

Comment: Do you mean 234.35 raised to the tenth power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert the integral part which is 11101010. Next, you build the decimal part. If demonstrated informally, it is something like:

0.1 is one half, but 0.35 is less than that, so the first binary digit is zero -> .0 (0.35)

0.01 is one quarter, and 0.35 is greater than that, so then follows one. 0.35 minus one quarter is decimal 0.1 -> .01 (0.35 - 0.25 = 0.1)

0.001 is one eighth, and decimal 0.1 is less than that, so again zero -> .010 (0.1)

Next steps are: .0101 (0.1 - 0.0625 = 0.0375); .01011 (0.0375 - 0.03125 = 0.00625); then follow two zeroes, and we can probably cut it here.

So, the answer is 11101010.010110... As the original number has decimal part of 7/20, it becomes infinite when converted to binary.

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely what I was looking for! Perfect answer!